# How to exclude classes from dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I have a project managed by maven, and I have following dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Please note that this hadoop is not from the official maven repository, it's generated by a team in my company.

When I deployed my project to tomcat, following exception generated when the tomcat starting:

```
15/01/02 12:17:08 ERROR servlet.DispatcherServlet: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.                 RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.   NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:957)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5516)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.      RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType.<init>(Ljava/  lang/Class;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
```

But if I remove hadoop-core from dependency, it is OK again. So I unzipped the hadoop-core.jar and found the content is like following:

```
$ ls
    about.html         gson-1.4.jar               jdiff                   NOTICE                                           slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
    asm-license.txt    guava-11.0.2.jar           jdtCompilerAdapter.jar  objenesis-license.txt                            slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar
    bin.tgz            hadoop-default.xml         jsr305-1.3.9.jar        org                                              src
    cglib-license.txt  hadoop-metrics.properties  junit                   org_apache_hadoop_conf_AutoDoc.properties        stylesheet.css
    client.login.conf  hamcrest-license.txt       junit3.8.1              org_apache_hadoop_conf_AutoDoc_zh_CN.properties  tasks.properties
    com                hsqlServlet.class          LICENSE                 overview.html                                    webapps
    COPYING            images                     LICENSE.txt             plugin.properties                                xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
    COPYRIGHT          jar                        log4j.properties        plugin.xml
    digesterRules.xml  javassist                  me                      properties.dtd
    dom4j-1.6.1.jar    javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar    META-INF                PropertyList-1.0.dtd
    eu                 javax                      net                     README




$ ls org/codehaus/jackson/
annotate              JsonFactory.class              JsonParseException.class       JsonToken.class      schema                    Versioned.class
Base64Variant.class   JsonGenerationException.class  JsonParser.class               map                  SerializableString.class
Base64Variants.class  JsonGenerator.class            JsonParser$Feature.class       node                 sym
impl                  JsonGenerator$Feature.class    JsonParser$NumberType.class    ObjectCodec.class    type
io                    JsonLocation.class             JsonProcessingException.class  package-info.class   util
JsonEncoding.class    JsonNode.class                 JsonStreamContext.class        PrettyPrinter.class  Version.class
```

So I think it's because the jackson introduced by hadoop-core is inconsistent with the current, and I configured the shade plugin by following:

```xml
<build>
    ...........
    <plugins>
        ............
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core</artifact>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>org/apache/hadoop/**</include>
                                </includes>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org/codehaus/jackson/**</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But it still not work, the same exception still exist. In order to confirm the origin of class org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType, I add the following code:

```
System.out.println("-------loading WebController-------");
ProtectionDomain pd = org.codehaus.jackson.type.JavaType.class.getProtectionDomain();
CodeSource cs = pd.getCodeSource();
System.out.println(cs.getLocation());
pd = org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.class.getProtectionDomain();
cs = pd.getCodeSource();
System.out.println(cs.getLocation());
```

and the result is:

```
-------loading WebController-------
file:/path/to/project/target/WEB-INF/lib/hadoop-core-1.1.3.2.jar
file:/path/to/project/target/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
```

At last, I am really puzzled. By the way, the config of tomcat is like this:

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context path="" docBase="/path/to/the/target/path/generated/by/maven/projectname" debug="0" reloadable="false" crossContext="true"          allowLinking="true"/>
    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
```

Comment: Basically, what you want to acomplish is to exclude one `.class` file from that _customized_ dependency jar so it won't clash with the same class defined in another dependency?

Comment: It's OK also. In short, my expectation is to resolve this exception. By the way, I am using a maven reposity provided by my company, and the hadoop-core is from this reposity. And I can not change the reposity.

Comment: By the way, do you know why shade plugin not work? Am I using it correctly? Indeed I am experienced with web techniques, but new to java.

Comment: Have a look at 'resource-transformers' http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html
. It have various options to add, merge, aggregate resources. Should get the job done.

Comment: I checked the link, but I found that only the resource with specific file suffix can be excluded by http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#DontIncludeResourceTransformer. By the way, why my shade plugin config not work?